# How to use shared memory between processes on POSIX system

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory

There are some processes use shared memory to do some synchronization. The `struct` in shared memory lists below:

```
struct Shm {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int a;
    bool b;
    double d;
};
```

Now each process will `mmap()` this shared memory, save the members to local variables and access them later:

```
// save members to local variables
void init() {
    void *ptr = mmap(nullptr, sizeof(Shm), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    auto shm = (Shm *)ptr;
    m_mutex = &shm->mutex;
    m_a = &shm->a;
    m_b = &shm->b;
    m_d = &shm->d;
}

// access shared memory with local variables
void print() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(m_mutex);
    std::cout << m_a << ", " << m_b << ", " << m_d << std::endl;
    *m_a = *m_a + 1;
    *m_b = !(*m_b);
    *m_d = *m_d / 2.0f;
}
```

So is the above code right to access the shared memory? Does compiler do some optimizations or cache the local variable and cause reading or writing error?
From `man mmap` on Linux, `MAP_SHARED` will share this mapping and updates to the mapping are visible to other processes mapping the same region.

Comment: You cannot use a mutex this way. For cross-process use a mutex must be initialised (and must use PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED attribute), but to initialise shared data (including a mutex), you already need some kind of interprocess synchronisation.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit .. If it's all the same, I'd really rather see you here. Reddit is a zoo for programming QA, even the R/cpp is a mess compared with SO. I'll still see you there, but I hardly see it as an equal alternative.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Yes. The shared memory and mutex will be created first to make sure other processes can use them properly. My confusion is about using the other  data in the shared memory, not the mutex.